# R - Fully remove cropped shapefile data

Tags: r, gis, geospatial

Is there a way to remove unused levels in a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` object in R?

I have large shapefile of geological data `Geology` that I am clipping with the `raster::crop` tool.  This seems to work fine.

But when I try to work using my new, cropped shapefile `Geo`, polygon types present in `Geology` but absent in area covered by `Geo` still appear as levels in `Geo`.  This interferes with my later analysis.

I have tried to remove these "ghost" levels/attributes using `droplevels`, but this function is not valid for `SpatialPolygons` or `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` objects.

For reference, I am using the `wygeol_dd_polygon.shp` shapefile (downloadable [here](http://pubs.usgs.gov/of/2005/1351/data/WYgeol_dd.zip) - 41.4 MB) as a starting point.  The salient parts of my code are below:

```
library(maptools)
Geology <- readShapePoly("~/wygeol_dd_polygon.shp")

library(raster)
Geo <- crop(Geology, extent(-111.05, -110.25, 44.2667, 44.7667))
```

After cropping, I have ten unique rock types, but still 46 levels:

```
unique(Geo$ROCKTYPE1)
 [1] alluvium                   rhyolite                   mixed clastic/volcanic     intermediate volcanic rock
 [5] basalt                     water                      trachyandesite             sandstone                 
 [9] conglomerate               shale                     
46 Levels: alkalic intrusive rock alkalic volcanic rock alluvium andesite anorthosite basalt carbonate clastic ... water
```

How do I get rid of these?

Comment: Is Geo$ROCKTYPE1 a factor? Not much experience of shape files but you can try Geo$ROCKTYPE1 <- factor(Geo$ROCKTYPE1)... R has a habit of retaining factor levels after crop, so you have to redefine the level by 'reinstating' as a factor

Comment: Wow - very easy!  I appreciate the help, thank you.  That seems to have done the trick.

Comment: No probs will post as an answer now - if you don't mind indicating that it answered your question for future reference for others that would be great

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Geo@data<-droplevels(Geo@data)
```

The above will handle all the factor columns in one call.

Comment: Nice solution - works for non-spatial data frames too?

Comment: See `?droplevels`. It is designed for `data.frame`s and `factor`s. The `data` slot of `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` is a standard `data.frame` and so `droplevels` can be used.

Comment: Cheers - will be potentially very useful for my coding efficiency!

Answer (score 1):

The column you are having issues with as a factor variable. When you crop factors in R, it often retains the cropped factors even though you no longer have any remaining in your dataset. Gladly it's an easy fix as follows:

```
Geo$ROCKTYPE1 <- factor(Geo$ROCKTYPE1)
```

This redefines the factor so now you should only have 10 levels, as you want.

Comment: Thanks again!  Your answer addresses my case specifically and works very well, but I opted to tag @nicola because it's a more general approach.